# user session timeout with timer

Tags: javascript, angular, session, rxjs

At the moment the app I'm working on is set up that when a user first interacts with a form, a session is created with an expiration time of 15 minutes,

Also, the session is setup server-side.

After 15 minutes, and if the user is idle (not interacted with the form) the server returns 404 and the user is logged out.

What is needed now is a warning, for when the user is 20 seconds away from timing out.

My idea is to poll the endpoint, to get info regarding session expiration time and when 20 seconds to go, alert the user.

My question is 2 fold, how often should the endpoint be called?

I think at least every 20 seconds

And, the first time I'm trying this method, I have fears of performance issues, if there are many users polling, won't this create lag, etc.?

Just need input of people who've had experience with this

Answer (score 1):

Polling isn't anything new and is being used pretty often. Everything depends on your server and the load of it. I would suggest, since you know exacly how long the session will last, to make the server return some value like `expiresAt` which will tell you when will the session time out, based on that you can show the warning on frontend without even having to poll the backend for it.